# IBM Notes on hotspot onmouseover event display contents of url link

Tags: lotus-notes

I need help with writing the javascript for a onmouseover event to display the contents of a url link when a mouse passes over a hotspot rectangle on an IBM Notes Page (Version 9).

[onmouseover event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snQxT.jpg)

Comment: can you show some code please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do this with JavaScript, you could just add the contents of the link URL as Alternate Text on the second tab of the Hotspot Properties dialog.